# Trigger Icon/Image Movement Via CSS After Elapsed Duration

Tags: html, css, image, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm a little new to web development so please forgive me if my terminology is off or something is blatantly obvious, but I have been unable to locate a solution thus far in my search. This issue is as follows: I have a webpage that I am displaying a number of icons that I have created or "sprites" (I believe the correct term) that successfully change, that is the background moves a number of pixels to display the colored portion (initially grey) of the image upon hovering. Which is reflected below when I call `.social-slide:hover`. However what I would like to accomplish is to have that "change" take place after a certain period of time (while keeping the hover function), such as when the page loads, or after 10 seconds. IE:

`.img-hover {background-image: url('images/img-hover.png'); background-position: 0px -48px;}` - After 5 seconds
`.img-hover2 {background-image: url('images/img-hover2.png'); background-position: 0px -48px;}`                                                                             - After 10 seconds

(Of course it should revert to its original grey state following that movement.) I have found a few `CSS` properties that are timed but many relate to the animation after it has already been called or is taken place. Is there a property or a method to initiate the icons to "fire" or change that I can call via `CSS` or `Javascript`? Thanks in advance, again sorry I'm a bit of a novice.

My `style.css`:

```
.social-slide {
height: 48px;
width: 48px;
margin: 10px;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
-webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
-moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
-o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
-ms-transition: all ease 0.3s;
transition: all ease 0.3s;
}
.social-slide:hover {
background-position: 0px -48px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
.img-hover {
background-image: url('images/img-hover.png');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need javascript to do this. Add your classes with a timeout. Add the correct id to the element you want it to effect so javascript selects the right one.

Here is a plunkr demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/RwQf2mrI1SsDe2ykvyFs

```
    <li>
<a id="five-delay" href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-hover social-slide" data-size="..." data-hashtags="..."></a>
</li>

    (function(window, document){
        //this will select the element you want to add the class to
        var fiveSecondDelay = document.getElementById('five-delay');

        //this function executes on page load
        window.onload = function(){
            //this calls the passed in function after X delay, 5 seconds in this case
            setTimeout(function(){
               //this will add the classes to the element after the 5 second delay
               fiveSecondDelay.className += 'twitter-hover social-slide';
            }, 5000);
        }
    })(window, document);
```

Comment: @ Kevin, Thanks for your reply. I appreciate it. Not the best with `Javascript`. Can you elaborate? For example if I set up the Icon as `<li><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-hover social-slide" data-size="..." data-hashtags="..."></a></li>` The accompanying script would be? `<script>(function(window, document){
    var fiveSecondDelay = document.getElementById('five-delay');
    window.onload = function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
           fiveSecondDelay.className += 'twitter-hover social-slide';
        }, 5000);
    }
})(window, document);</script>`

Comment: Added comments and a demo